# Angular Routing and Paths

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a group of images at my root level and I also have a page called Help.  If I navigate to rootspace/Help angular knows to get the images from the root repository, but if I change it to rootspace/Help/ then angular thinks the files are in a folder 'Help' that doesn't exist.  I need the extra slash because I want to put more information after it.

How can I maintain '/Help/' without angular thinking this is part of the path it needs to find resources?

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the images? I'd recommend creating a [resouce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), this way angular will always know where to find the images if you provide a base url. It will also be easy to configure later on if you change the location of the images.

Example code:

```
angular.module('resources', ['$resource'])
    .factory('Images', function($resource) {
        return $resource(baseUrlGoesHere + '/images', {}, {})      
    })
```

Then you can inject the resource into your controller and call `Images.get()`

BTW, you probably can't use the code as is, I think the injection of $resource will fail but I'm not sure.